# “I am hungry/hunger of/for knowledge”

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions, collocation

I am not sure which one is the correct one:

> A: I am hungry of knowledge.
>   B: I hunger of knowledge.
>   C: I am hungry for knowledge.
>   D: I hunger for knowledge.

But my feeling says that A and B are the correct ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct preposition is *for*. One is hungry *for* knowledge. One can also hunger for it.

Answer (score 3):

C and D are both correct. However, "I hunger for" is not a common usage (writing as an Australian of British origin).

Comment: Yet "hunger for" is perfectly acceptable. It may not be colloquial or something you hear every day, but it's not weird of awkward.

Comment: @Robusto: Agreed. It sounds a bit old fashioned or literary to me. You might consider adding to your answer that D is possible.

Comment: "I Hunger for" is used widely, though it is far more common to say "I have a thirst for", particularly used with *knowledge*; "he has a thirst for knowledge".

Comment: Strangely, I think it actually only sounds awkward if you say "I hunger for spaghetti" or some other actual food.  If you use it metaphorically, "hunger for" doesn't sound awkward or overly stuffy.  Gotta love language!

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I suspect that metaphoric usage often stays alive longer than literal usage. Just as many of our abstract words have concrete roots that are long forgotten.

Comment: @Cerberus, @Kosmonaut: Well, I rarely hunger or thirst for things I don't have, but I often yearn for them. Sometimes I lust *after* them, but that's another matter entirely ...

Answer (score 2):

A and B are incorrect. C and D are both correct, choose which one looks better in the sentence as their meaning is practically the same.. just different verb tenses :)

Comment: Right, but note that they are both in the present tense.

Comment: I think the difference you are looking for is that *hungry* is an adjective and *hunger* is a verb.