# Better wording for "greedy for knowledge"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm writing recommendation for one of my colleagues and one of the points I'd like to highlight is his "greed/hunger for knowledge".

Something like: X is very greedy for knowledge, taking each opportunity to improve his expertise.

Frankly speaking I doubt that using such phrase is good in official document, thus I'd like to ask you for any suggestion how such expression can be written. (disclaimer - English is not my native language)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What term means "one who enjoys learning"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163232/what-term-means-one-who-enjoys-learning) Also related: [I am hungry/hunger of/for knowledge](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8547/i-am-hungry-hunger-of-for-knowledge/393069)

Comment: Also of related interest: *[Connotations of "hungry for X" and "thirsty for X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239219/connotations-of-hungry-for-x-and-thirsty-for-x)*

Answer (score 1):

***VORACIOUS***

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary  (https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/voracious) :

: excessively eager:

INSATIABLE

// a voracious reader

According to Learner's Dictionary

(http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/VORACIOUS%20):

***VORACIOUS*** 
is often used figuratively:

She has a voracious appetite for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

***Inquisitive***

It means someone who takes great interest in learning things. 
*His great expertise in the field can be attributed to his inquisitiveness.*

You can use *agog*, which is used when someone is very excited about something, esp to *see* something.
*He is all agog to take on new responsibilities.*

Or you can simply use the word *curious*, but if you are wanting a more emphatic expression then it might fall flat.

Other words can be *enquiring* (adjective), *alacrity* (noun)..

*Voracious* is a great word but I feel its mostly used in the context of food.